# After add react-native-firebase crashlytics the Android App crashes in the second build with classNotFound Exception for MainApplication

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I configured the react-native-firebase and crashlytics in my application. The iOS build is successfully worked.

but when I run `react-native run-android` for the second time the app installed in the phone but it is crashed following is the `adb logcat` for application

> I/ActivityManager(  611): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.company.mobile/.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10039 on display 0
>   W/AudioTrack(  611): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
>   E/libprocessgroup( 4404): failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10059: Read-only file system
>   W/Zygote  ( 4404): createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
>   I/art     ( 4404): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   I/ActivityManager(  611): Start proc com.company.mobile for activity com.company.mobile/.MainActivity: pid=4404 uid=10059 gids={50059, 9997, 3003} abi=x86
>   D/AndroidRuntime( 4404): Shutting down VM
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404): Process: com.company.mobile, PID: 4404
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.company.mobile.MainApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.company.mobile.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.mobile-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.company.mobile-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:563)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4491)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.company.mobile.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.mobile-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.company.mobile-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:979)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:558)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    ... 10 more
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.mobile.MainApplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):        ... 13 more
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4404):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
>   W/ActivityManager(  611):   Force finishing activity com.company.mobile/.MainActivity
>   I/WindowManager(  611): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{1fd4adee ActivityRecord{3c07bf69 u0 com.company.mobile/.MainActivity t20 f}} appWin=Window{553e925 u0 Starting com.company.mobile} drawState=1
>   E/ActivityManager(  611): Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 768x768
>   W/art     (  611): Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(com.android.server.am.ProcessRecord, android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$CrashInfo) from ActivityManagerService.java:12038 waiters=0 for 325ms
>   I/OpenGLRenderer(  611): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   W/art     (  611): Long monitor contention event with owner method=int com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow(com.android.server.wm.Session, android.view.IWindow, int, android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams, int, int, int, int, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.Rect, android.content.res.Configuration, android.view.Surface) from WindowManagerService.java:2977 waiters=0 for 574ms
>   I/Choreographer( 1497): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   W/EGL_emulation(  611): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   W/OpenGLRenderer(  611): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xda5123c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
>   I/Choreographer(  611): Skipped 96 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   W/ActivityManager(  611): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{3c07bf69 u0 com.company.mobile/.MainActivity t20 f}
>   I/Choreographer(  611): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   W/EGL_emulation( 1497): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   W/OpenGLRenderer( 1497): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xdf214c40, error=EGL_SUCCESS

My AndroidManifest

> 

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.company.mobile"><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

----------- main application -------------

```
    package com.company.mobile;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewPackage;
import com.microsoft.appcenter.reactnative.crashes.AppCenterReactNativeCrashesPackage;
import com.microsoft.appcenter.reactnative.analytics.AppCenterReactNativeAnalyticsPackage;
import com.microsoft.appcenter.reactnative.appcenter.AppCenterReactNativePackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerPackage;

import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.fabric.crashlytics.RNFirebaseCrashlyticsPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new AppCenterReactNativeCrashesPackage(MainApplication.this, getResources().getString(R.string.appCenterCrashes_whenToSendCrashes)),
          new AppCenterReactNativeAnalyticsPackage(MainApplication.this, getResources().getString(R.string.appCenterAnalytics_whenToEnableAnalytics)),
          new AppCenterReactNativePackage(MainApplication.this),
          new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
          new RNFirebasePackage(),
          new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
          new RNFirebaseCrashlyticsPackage(),
          new RNCWebViewPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

[image: mainApp]
[image: manifest]

Comment: added @ManojPerumarath

Comment: I didnt get you ?? but my problem is when I run the application first time using `react-native run-android` it works after first time the app crashes in the mobile it shows `Unfortunatly mobile has stopped`

Comment: check inside com.package files, along with mainactivity , mainapplication file is there  or not

Comment: it is there the MainApplication.java and MainActivity.java is in the com>mobile folder

Comment: added @ManojPerumarath

Comment: did you modify the package name? @Dileepa Chandima

Comment: yes it is not `com.company.mobile` it is our company name in the middle @ManojPerumarath

Comment: @DileepaChandima did you manage to resolve this issue? Seeing the same behaviour, having to run a clean in between each grade build to avoid crashes

Answer (score 2):

Modify

```
<application
android:name=".MainApplication"
```

to

```
<application
android:name="com.company.mobile.MainApplication"
```

If you've modified the package name then replace it with the one.

Also make sure that in manifest you're importing the correct package

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      package="com.company.mobile">
```

Comment: same issue happening :(

Comment: did you update the package name in the top of maniapplicaton class also

Comment: I'm not changing the package names, when I posted the code to here I just change them only

Comment: you have done something wrong with package names, please post the current package name by adding a screenshot to question

Comment: when I build the app after clean the app by `./gradlew clean` the application working fine but after that if I run it on 2nd time the app crashes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196553/discussion-between-dileepa-chandima-and-manoj-perumarath).